# How to write if else if statement in jquery where condition set by wordpress option setting

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, if-statement, jquery-selectors

How to pass wordpress option setting value as condition to toggle jquery function using if else statement?

Wordpress option setting value is 'select-type' value which is grabbed in my template using

```
<?php echo get_option('my_animation_module') ?>
```

which may print only one value like animation1, animation2, animation3 and so far..

I want to pass this option value as a condition in jquery to get diffrent animation effect using this wordpress option value.

HTML :

```
<div id="content-page>
<img src="images/myimage.png"/> 
<div>
```

Jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    $('#content-page').hover(function() {
            $(this).find('img').stop(false,true).animate({'top':480, 'left':270}, {duration:600});
                   },

        function() {
            $(this).find('img').stop(false,true).animate({'top':0, 'left':270}, {duration:500});

        });

      });
```

This is my first sample animation effect using jQuery. I want to add diffrent animation effect on image and those get shuffled using if else statement in jQuery and wordpress option value as condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        $(document).ready(function(){ 

             if('<?php echo get_option('my_animation_module') ?>' == "animation1")
             {
             //js code for animation1
             }
             else if('<?php echo get_option('my_animation_module') ?>' == "animation2")
             {
             //js code for animation2
             }
             else if('<?php echo get_option('my_animation_module') ?>' == "animation3")
             {
             //js code for animation3
             }


        });
```

Updated answer as requested

Can I grab this option value in jQuery by storing it as a variable ? Yes. See the eg.

```
var myval = '<?php echo get_option('my_animation_module') ?>';
alert(myval);
```

Comment: @Dasun-Yes its ok. Actually I never knew that I can get my wordpress option value directly in jQuery. Can I grab this option value in jQuery by storing it as a variable ?

Answer (score 1):

If your jQuery code is small, you can put it inline IN THE BOTTOM of the HTML document, just before < /html >, then echo PHP data as Dasun showed.

If your code is bigger, u'd better put it in a separated js file. To send data to that code in the file, in HTML document you just set a JS variable with the data, and in the main code uou test if that variable was set and if so you process it.

```
<script>
var mydata = <?php echo $mydata; ?>;
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Hikari its usefull, I will try this.